# Optimize mysql query with subquery in values list

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize queries to my database. I have the following query:

```
select date, (
    select count(user_id) 
    from myTable 
    where logdate = date
) as value 
from myTable;
```

As far as I can see, the second value is computed efficiently. However, is there any common practice to optimize this kind of query in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can avoid writing a subquery and preform the same query using aggregation, which may run faster:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(user_id) AS numRecords
FROM myTable
GROUP BY date;
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) on aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to put group functions in a separate select.  Just do

```
select date, count(user_id) from myTable group by date;
```

There is no hard and fast.  In this query, it was a matter of one select being more efficient than 2.  But here is [some tips for beginners](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-query-tuning.htm) on optimizing queries.